# Can I Theme the Messaging app's interface?

Tags: sms

When my Droid updated to Android 2.2 the Messaging app changed to a very light colored interface and I can't find any settings that allow me to change it back to the light text on dark background theme. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There are alternative, customisable SMS apps though, like ChompSMS or Handcent SMS.